# How to convert words to sentences?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I want to convert a long string of words to sentences with punctation etc.

i.e.
I input `"Hello my name is josef do you have some pizza"` 
and it outputs `"Hello, my name is Josef! Do you have some pizza?"`

What APIs, modules, code examples are existing to do something like this with nodejs?!
It must be able to handle long strings (like >5000 words)
How is this procedure called? NLP?

Comment: NLP is a very hard computer science branch with many, many problems. This comment won't help you thought, but I think you must know this. What if my name is `Josef Do You Have Some Pizza`?

Comment: In my opinion this kind of question is too broad for Stack Overflow - you will receive lots of differing opinions without any "correct" answer

Comment: Thanks for your input!
Is there something which at least recognizes sentences ??
ie "Hello my name is josef do you have some pizza" -> "Hello my name is josef. do you have some pizza." ???